# JPA insert query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have a dimension entity and I am trying to insert the records in it through JPA named/native query.

```
  public void insertData(String sql){
    getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql).executeUpdate();
    getEntityManager().flush();
  }
```

String sql is an insert statement for 60 records.

After calling this method, when I try to do :

```
  dimensionRepository.insertData(sql); //successful
  dimensionRepository.findAll(); //gives empty result list
```

I want to understand why the records were not inserted, and also, how to run insert query for JPA managed entities.

As per the request sql looks like this :

```
INSERT INTO `dimension` (`id`, `year_no`, `day`)
VALUES
    ('2016-01-01', 2016, 'Friday');
```

Comment: please also post you queries

Comment: Are you using `Transaction` or not ?The entity object is physically updated in the database when the transaction is committed. If the transaction not committed the update is discarded.

Comment: Thanks Mihir, I am using @Transactional, but I think this is the issue, I am trying to insert and select in the same transaction, maybe the insert were not committed, till the time I am querying, Can I commit explicitly, I thought flush() will do that?

Comment: @greperror If you are using `@Transactional` then no need to commit explicitly. Are you getting any exception in logs after insert/update successful ?

Comment: no, I am not getting any errors in the log, actually I have 2 entities, on 1st entity I am doing persist(), while on entity2 I am doing native query insert, The 1st entity() show records on findAll(), while 2nd does not. Does persist and native query insert behave differently.